# pdfbox: how to load a font once and use it many times?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to create a lot of pdf files in a loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; ++i){
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputstream);
    PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
    content.beginText();
    //what happens here?
    PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("font/simsun.ttf") );
    content.setFont(font, 10);
    //...
    doc.save(outstream);
    doc.close();
}
```

what does it happen by calling `PDType0Font.load...` ? Because the ttf file is large (10M), will it create ephemeral big objects of `font` 10000 times? If so, is there a way to make the font as embedded as PDType1Font, so I can just load it once and use it many times in the loop?
I encountered a full GC problem here, and I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Don't forget to close `content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the font at the fontbox level:

```
TrueTypeFont ttf = new TTFParser().parse(...);
```

You can now reuse `ttf` in different `PDDocument` objects like this:

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, ttf, true);
```

When done with all documents, don't forget to close `ttf`.

See also `PDFontTest.testPDFBox3826()` in the source code.